# What is the meaning of "bought the field into existence" in this sentence?

Tags: usage

I saw it on a book about occupational therapy
What is the meaning of "bought the field into existence" in this sentence?

**The observation that engagement in an occupation had the potential to transform people is bought the field into existence.**

Comment: Is this sentence copied word for word from your source?

Comment: http://books.google.com.hk/books?id=WWX2AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA156&lpg=PA156&dq=occupational+therapy+homework&source=bl&ots=AO5DaZQy4t&sig=kVlxHKjD8J0bNR3GgXBH5bukRIc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8Lw4VO3LOsT_8QWUoIHABQ&ved=0CEMQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q&f=false   the big blue box on page3

Comment: The sentence there actually ends *is **what brought** the field into existence*. Does that correction dispel your confusion? If so, your question is based on a misreading and you should probably delete it; if you are still confused, please edit your question to make this correction, and indicate exactly where you have a problem.

Comment: StoneyB is right. It should be what brought

Comment: engagement in an occupation= working.....................
bought the field into existence=field of occupational therapy........................
So, how can "observe people working" link with "transform people" and "brought the field of occupational therapy into existence "?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a simple typo in that book. Instead of *bought*, it should be *brought*. Also instead of *is*, it should be *has*, for past tense, since the field is already in existence.

I believe it should read like this :

> The observation that engagement in an occupation had the potential to
>   transform people has brought the field into existence.

Meaning that observation, has brought the field of occupational therapy into existence.

Comment: But what transform people ?

Comment: @DenizÇağlayan That likely means one or more of the following. That engagement in their work, helped these workers be more productive, be happier, believe that the work they are doing has a real purpose.  So to *not* be engaged in your work, would be like daydreaming all the time during work, and just hoping that the work day would end very soon... instead of where, engaging is focusing on what they are doing, and b.c they are focused on their work, they are not focusing on how much they hate their job or about what they will eat when they go home. They are living in the present, not future.